# How to determine if Windows was upgraded

Tags: c#, windows

I need to find out if my application is running on a freshly installed Windows 10 machine or if its an upgrade from an old Windows Version (7 or 8.1).

I first though of looking for a "Windows.old" but this could be deleted.

Is there a registry key to find out the previous Windows Version?

Thanks
Flo

Comment: May I ask why you need this? Googled a few secs have you looked at: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-determine-if-pc-has-clean-or-upgrade-installation-windows-10

Comment: I have some issue with a driver, if windows was updated it could be necessary to reinstall the driver. I like to give the user a hint for that workaround.

Comment: It would be a better idea to figure out if the driver works in some way that doesn't depend on how Windows was installed/upgraded (as in, the actual differences in driver registration/files between working and non-working installations). This would allow you to cover more cases without relying on the relatively brittle indication of whether Windows happened to be upgraded at some point (what if the next version of Windows 10 breaks things even for fresh installs)?

Comment: The problem is in WinUsb installed from a inf file on Win7 and than upgraded to Win10. I like to show the user a hint while we work on a solution for that problem. So it should be a temporary help.

Comment: @Rand Random .. that it thanks! You find the Previous version under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\DownlevelBuildNumber

Comment: Wrong kind of oracle.  What you *really* want to tell the user about is a bad version of a driver file.  Use the FileVersionInfo class.

Comment: Thats a good idear, thanks I will give it a try.